# Invisible team project branch preventing solution branching in TFS 2012 - Error TF203028

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I branched a team project, then later deleted it through the source control explorer. So now i'm trying to branch parent solution, but i keep getting the error

```
TF203028: You cannot create a branch at $/ACID/Source because a branch already exists at $/ACID/Source/Acid.Web-branch-selectStyle. If $/ACID/Source/Acid.Web-branch-selectStyle is not a branch convert it back to a folder and retry the operation.
```

The thing is, this branch does not exist anymore, and so i can't delete or convert its folder. And thus i can't branch my solution at all.

Currently there are no branchs in my solution, not visible through the source control explorer at least.

Any ideas? I'm using VS2013.3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have not deleted it, only stopped it's history. If you go to Visual Studio | Tools | Settings | Source Control you should see a "View deleted items" option. This will give you an undelete option. However I think you just want to destroy the code so that you can reuse the location.

You can use "tf destroy" to actually remove all history of a source location. Note however that this totally unrecoverable.

Comment: Once you are able to view the deleted child folder, you can convert branch from that deleted child folder and then it should allow you to convert parent folder into a Branch.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option for you, deleting the root and then re-creating it allowed me to get around this without having to use the destroy command.